# Select query in FOR loop does not works in Netezza

Tags: plpgsql, netezza, nzplsql

I am trying to run a simple plsql in Netezza, to run a loop on a result set of select query,
here is the below code I am trying to run

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_SUSPECT_GROUP_ID() 
RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY) EXECUTE AS CALLER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
    DECLARE
        VAL BIGINT := 100000000000000;
    BEGIN
        RAISE NOTICE 'lets start';
        FOR r IN 
            select 
                suspect_id as suspect_id
            from apollo_customer_analysis.ASHKUMAR.REFINED_SUSPECT

        LOOP
        
            RAISE NOTICE 'val: %',r.suspect_id;
            
        END LOOP;
    END;
END_PROC;

EXECUTE UPDATE_SUSPECT_GROUP_ID();
```

When try to run the code, I get the below error

```
ERROR [01000] NOTICE:  plpgsql: ERROR during compile of UPDATE_SUSPECT_GROUP_ID near line 15
ERROR [01000] NOTICE:  line 1 at execute statement
ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting LOOP at or near ";"
```

Can someone help me how this error could be resolved?

Comment: plpgsql is Postgres, nzplsql is IBM Netezza, and PL/SQL is Oracle. I don't think this is Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: In PL/SQL a cursor FOR loop uses brackets, e.g. `for r in (select blah from etc) loop`. Maybe whatever language this is needs brackets too. (Wild guess.)